Examples of lamellar microstructure growth driven by ion replacement
Let me present an analogy between:

The well-known directed lamellar microstructure formed from an eutectic melt by cooling.
An unknown (to me, so far) but probably possible lamellar microstructure formed in an electrochemical setup.

In the latter, instead of heat conductivity driving heat out, ionic conductivity through the solid is used to drive one type of ions out while - from the melt side - another type of ions is driven in. Voltage is maintained between the growing solid and the consumed liquid and its ion source.
If the contact area of the melt and its ion source is made larger than the liquid-solid interface, the concentration of the in-diffusing ion is going to be slightly lower near the ion source because, given low enough current, diffusion spreads the ions evenly over the melt volume. The solidification (without significant temperature differences in this whole system) is driven by the differing ion type concentrations - starting composition just above its melting point, evolving towards a higher melting point composition, constant temperature. The solid conducts only one type of ions. The liquid (for simplicity) conducts two types of ions, which have the same sign of charge.
Now, the tricky part is: how to make the solid microstructure lamellar and its mechanism of solidification analogous to heat-flow-driven eutectic solidification. OTOH, I have absolutely no reason to think this is impossible, because, on phase diagrams (composition vs temperature), eutectic points are ubiquitous and - as an analogy - one could replace the temperature axis by molar heat content axis: the diagram must be redrawn but the eutectic points (maybe lines now?) are still there. Heat isn't any different from any other components, therefore - for case 2. - let's assume instead an extra component (ion type mentioned above) which - by analogy to heat at constant temperature - saturates the main composition and - by analogy to changing temperature - can be replaced by the second type ion and the ratio of the types can be shown on an axis replacing the temperature axis.
Question:
Am I wasting my time reinventing something that is already done routinely by professional chemists or is the above-described process unknown?
If the former, I'd like to see an example. Alternatively, if the situation is unrealistic, I'd like to know why is this the case.

Are you asking if it is possible to create lamellar structure electrochemically?

Yes, for this specific sort of process only. Have you a good reason against this possibility?
